# Language select: how to set up

Tags: entities, i18n-l10n

In the current set up for every English page, there's a Spanish equivalent.  Each page has its own unique URL.

Previously we had it set up so that you could click "Spanish" within the English page and it would call the Spanish URL and visa-versa.

We've been asked to make it global -a button at the top of the site.

Is there a clean way to detect what the Spanish equivalent is of the current page with PHP and make the switch?

Answer (score 2):

Locale module by default provides you a block, Language Switcher, that switches language of the site. It's a list of installed language.

If you like a fancy switcher, you can install this module:
[Language Switcher Dropdown](https://drupal.org/project/lang_dropdown)

> Language Switcher Dropdown is a very simple module that exposes a new
>   block, similar to the default Language Switcher block provided by
>   Locale module. The new block allows site visitors to switch languages
>   using a drop-down select list instead of using hyperlinks.
>
> The module also integrates well with [Language Icons](https://drupal.org/project/languageicons) module if
>   installed.

[Here's an example](https://drupal.org/files/images/Screen%20shot%202011-03-29%20at%2017.51.18%20.png)

Answer (score 0):

I use i18n serie for multilingual websites and there is a block language which works on its own for this purpose. I'm not sure to understand your multilingual setup, if it is not using i18n, I wouldn't say if you can use it independantly from the i18n suite. More info here: https://drupal.org/node/1279698